# Is there a way to determine what nouns take the ending "-у" in the locative case?

Tags: падежи, окончания

While researching this question, I encountered something called `местный падеж` according to the wikipages for [`пол`](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB) and [`берег`](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3).

A teacher once told me that there are certain words that take the ending `-у` in this case and that there are three rules that apply:

1. These words are monosyllabic
2. They're masculine
3. The -y ending is stressed

However, that didn't help me and I'm suspicious of those rules. The noun `берег` has two syllables with the first one stressed.

Can someone explain:

- What those words are?
- What rules do apply?
- How to recognize them, if possible?
- When to use the `locative` and when <strike>`genitive`</strike> `prepositional падеж`?

Bonus

- Why does the accent shift to the ending?

**My assumptions**

- Some words simply have this *additional ending* `-y`

> БЕРЕГ, -а; предлож. о береге, на берегу; мн. берега, -ов; м.
> ШКАФ, -а, предл. о шкафе, в шкафу; мн. шкафы; м.
> ПОЛ, -а (-у), предлож. о поле, на полу; мн. полы
> ЛЕС, -а (-у), предл. о лесе, в лесу; мн. леса, -ов;
> ХОД, -а (-у), предлож. в ходе и в ходу, на ходе и на ходу; мн. ходы; м.
> ...gramota.ru

- There's no way to recognize them right away (most of them seem to be monosyllabic, but `берег` has two syllables e.g.).
- `-у` is answers the question `Where?` — otherwise the regular prepositional ending -e is used.
- When `-y` is used, it's *always* stressed.

**Edit:** Later in the source that u.hrybok cited, it also says:

> Формы второго предложного падежа в морфологическом отношении отличаются тем, что у **слов женского рода это окончание обязательно принимает ударение** (ср. разбирается в кро́ви [Предл1] vs. испачкан в крови́ [Предл2]) [5], а у **слов мужского рода имеется специализированное окончание -у́** (**также всегда ударное**, ср. заинтересован в шка́фе [Предл1] vs. хранится **в шкафу́** [Предл2]).

Comment: I'm afraid all you can do it to memoize all the list, there're no mnemonic rule to my knowledge.

Comment: Other two and three-syllable words that have Locative are ветер, повод and аэропорт. Ветер and повод have stress on the first syllable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but берег has two syllables

Maybe the reason for this is that аrchaic form of the word "берег" is "брег"...

However, "на бреге".

I think I found the answer:

> Особые формы [3] второго предложного падежа, отличные от основного предложного, существуют, однако, у очень ограниченной группы русских неодушевленных существительных, причем только в парадигме единственного числа. В эту группу входят порядка двадцати существительных женского рода традиционного третьего склонения (т.е. слова типа пыль) и порядка ста двадцати существительных мужского рода традиционного второго склонения с основой на морфонологически твердый [4] согласный или -j (т.е. слова типа шкаф, строй). Практически все эти слова имеют односложную основу, **за исключением следующих девяти** (все они мужского рода): **берег, ветер, перёд, повод, угол, отпуск, терем, холод и аэропорт**; **еще два слова, ворот и корень**, имеют форму локатива только в составе устойчивых сочетаний брань на вороту не виснет и (сгнить / истребить / скупить и т.п.) на корню ~ 'в процессе роста; в самом начале; целиком'.

Learn more: [К СЕМАНТИКЕ РУССКОГО ЛОКАТИВА ("ВТОРОГО ПРЕДЛОЖНОГО" ПАДЕЖА)](http://www.philology.ru/linguistics2/plungyan-02.htm)

Comment: Брег is not archaic form! It is Church Slavonic form while берег is native Russian form. -1.

Comment: @Anixx OK, I don't insist on the wording of "archaic form".
Would be correct to say that "брег" - is a translation to some other Slavonic languages​​.
PS I had to remove it from the answer when I added the second part

Answer (score 4):

Masculine nouns that have locative:

```
снег в снегу о снеге
дым в дыму о дыме
лес в лесу о лесе
плац на плацу о плаце
ров во рву о рве
берег на берегу о береге
мир в миру о мире (here мир means "life outside church", in the meaning of peace and world, locative is not used)
стог в стогу о стоге
долг в долгу о долге
вид на виду о виде
пруд в пруду о пруде
день на дню о дне
нос в носу о носе
глаз в глазу о глазе
таз в тазу о тазе
паз в пазу о пазе
воз на возу о возе
ряд в ряду о ряде
век на веку о веке
строй в строю о строе
бред в бреду о бреде
ветер на ветру о ветре
мел в мелу о меле
тыл в тылу о тыле
пол на полу о поле
пыл в пылу о пыле
бой в бою о бое
ход на ходу о ходе
жар в жару о жаре
стыд в стыду о стыде
быт в быту о быте
пир на пиру о пире
рот во рту о рте
пар на пару о паре
дух на духу о духе 
мост на мосту о мосте
борт на борту о борте
год в году о годе
час в часу о часе
бег на бегу о беге
лёт на лету о лёте (Prepositional is not generally used)
порт в порту о порте
аэропорт в аэропорту об аэропорте
пот в поту о поте
жир в жиру о жире
род в роду о роде
сад в саду о саде
зад в заду о заде
шкаф в шкафу о шкафе
полк при полку о полке
мозг в мозгу о мозге
лёд на льду о льде
сук на суку о суке
раз на разу о разе
рай в раю о рае
угол в углу об угле
бор в бору о боре
свет на свету о свете
вес на весу о весе
дом на дому о доме
гроб в гробу о гробе
чад в чаду о чаде
хлев в хлеву о хлеве
Крым в Крыму о Крыме
Клин в Клину о Клине
край на краю о крае
вал на валу о вале
повод на поводу о поводе
луг на лугу о луге
бок на боку о боке
мех в меху о мехе
пух в пуху о пухе
пост на посту о посте
скок на скаку о скоке (Prepositional is not generally used)
ад в аду об аде
слух на слуху о слухе
сок в соку о соке
пыл в пылу о пыле
клей в клею о клее
```

Feminine nouns that have locative (difference in the stress):

```
тень в тенИ о тЕни
грязь в грязИ о грЯзи
пыль в пылИ о пЫли
грудь в грудИ о грУди
сень в сенИ о сЕни
ночь в ночИ о нОчи
даль в далИ о дАли
мель на мелИ о мЕли
сеть в сетИ о сЕти
печь в печИ о пЕчи
кровь в кровИ о крОви
ось на осИ об Оси
рысь на рысИ о рЫси
связь в связИ о свЯзи
```

Feminine nouns that have locative forms in plural (difference in the stress and е-ё):

```
слЁзы в слезАх о слЁзах
сОпли в соплЯх о сОплях
слЮни в слюнЯх о слЮнях
Ясли в яслЯх о Яслях
слАсти в сластЯх о слАстях
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to explain, but this is my first answer in the language section of the stack, so feel free to ask me.

The Russian `locative case` is similar to the `prepositional case`, so word thus declined answers the question `where?`. But the main difference is that the `locative` give us information about the noun's position. At any rate, this difference is so small, that there's no separate `locative case` in Russian — it simply tends to fall under and be use alongside the `prepositional case`.
For example:

```
- Where's Your largest birthmark located? 
- On my side.
```

In Russian:

```
- Где твоя самая большая родинка?
- На **боку**.
```

1. The `locative case` specifies the place of an action, so we commonly encounter phrases such as `в лесу`, `в городе`, etc.
2. There are two preposition used with the `locative case`: `в` и `на` *(в лесу, на дереве)*.
3. The `locative` is the `prepositional` that specifies the place where an action takes place.
4. Use the `locative` if the noun is meant to answer the question `Where?` and specifies the place of action. Anyway, you'll use rules pertaining to the `prepositional case` because the `locative` is a part of it.

Bonus:

I have no idea

Comment: If you read carefully the question you'll see you actually do not answer it at all.

Comment: @shabunc ok, I'll correct my answer

Comment: there are some helpful things you mentioned. However the question is mainly about the additional ending `-y` which some words (`лес, берег, шкаф..`) seem to have

Answer (score 0):

There are about thirty or fourty words of the second masculine declension (masculine words ending with a consonant) whose Locative (-у like на мосту - on the/a bridge) is not the same as the Prepositional (-е like о мосте- about the/a bridge) case. They are mostly one- or two-syllable, but one must just learn these words. The Locative is used after prepositions в and на if the meaning of the group is either place or time. The most common words of this list are:

- мост;
- (аэро)порт;
- лес;
- год;
- берег;
- бок;
- бой;
- шкаф.

There is also word ход which is difficult, because there are expressions "в ходу" that means "widely used" and "на ходу" that means "while moving/driving/flying/piloting", but in usual usage Locative of ход is ходе - the same as Prepositional, as for most words.

Comment: Does this group of words have a name? Can they be found somewhere listed?

Comment: I disagree with your claim that Locative for ход is ходе. Can you give an example of such usage?

Comment: @Anixx "В ходе (наземной, десантной, etc.) операции" (="Во время операции", so it is case of Locative rather than Prepositional case)