# Is there ever a time when one uses по́ле to refer to the floor?

Tags: падежи

I recently wrote the following sentence as a practice exercise:

**We can sleep on the floor.

Мы можем спать на по́ле.**

After writing it, I learned that **"по́ле" should be "полу́"** and that "полу́" is in the locative case.  I had already done some reading on the locative case previously, but clearly I need more practice before I consistently and accurately assess the need for it.  Be that as it may, it made me take a look at all the cases that the word "пол" can take.  In the process, I learned that not all nouns have a need for a locative case.  For example, "по́ле" (field) does not appear to have a locative case.

---

*Is there a list of nouns that do take the locative case?  And is there any rhyme or reason to it?  I ask this because if there is any sort of pattern to it, why would something like a "floor" need locative case, but not a "field?"  If anyone happens to have either a list of nouns with a locative case or know of some sort of rule that helps one identify the types of nouns that would require it, what a helpful resource that would be.*

---

Another thing I noticed, however, is that "пол" has a prepositional case, something I am assuming all Russian nouns have.  (If there are any that do not, please enlighten me.)  The thing is, I cannot come up with an example of when it would be used and all the examples I've seen of the prepositional case for "по́ле" are clearly referring to a "field" and not a "floor."  **Is there ever a time when one uses по́ле to refer to the floor?**  And if so, could you provide some examples?

Comment: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/Категория:Русские_существительные_с_местным_падежом

Comment: @Quassnoi - that worth to be an answer. See also [Locative case - Местный падеж](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6). There seem to be no rhyme or reason for locative case. It seems to be a relic of Proto-Slavic language.

Comment: I just checked out your link.  What a great resource!  I concur with Alexander in that it could suffice as an answer, but still I would like to know if "по́ле" (as a prepositional case of "пол") "ever refers to a "floor," and if examples could be provided, even better.  I'll leave this question open for a bit to see if that can't be answered, but if not, I definitely think I'd give Quassnoi's link in an answer post the green checkmark.  Oh but nevermind, I see he has already done so.  Once again, ,болбшое спасибоб, Quassnoi.

Comment: @Alexander: all nouns with locative are either declension II male or declension III, but aside from this no rhyme or reason indeed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a list of nouns that do take the locative case?

Besides the Wiktionary link already provided by @Quassnoi, there is the *Grammatical Dictionary of Russian* by Andrey Zalizniak which lists these nouns:

- [Nouns with distinct forms for Locative](http://gramdict.ru/search/*?additional=%D0%9F%3Csub%3E2%3C%2Fsub%3E)

Such nouns are marked with **П<sub>2</sub>**:

- **бе́рег** м 3c①, П2(на)
- **ад** м 1a—, П2(в)

The words in parenthesis are the prepositions to be used. Thus, one should say **на берегу́** and **в аду́** but not **в берегу́** or **на аду́**.

We're losing Locative to the normal Propositional and it happens very fast - as we speak (literally!). Word by word. Such words have **П<sub>2</sub>** in square brackets:

- дуб м 1c, [П2(на)]

This means that both **на дубу́** and **на ду́бе** are correct.

Comment: Super helpful answer, Sergey.  So good, in fact, that I had to give you the green check mark instead!

Comment: @LisaBeck Thank you, Lisa. Glad you found my answer useful.

Answer (score 9):

Sure, with any preposition except *в* or *на*:

> - … богатым было и внутреннее убранство церкви: старики упоминали о паркетном поле и хрустальном паникадиле
> - При наливном поле она (*демпферная лента*) устанавливается с целью компенсировать расширения бетона при нагреве, чтобы избежать его растрескивания.